# Can't connect to SQL database with mysql++

Tags: c++, mysql, service, mysql++

I've been trying to use the mysql++ library in my application (windows x64 based) but I can't seem to connect to my sql server.
Some information:

I used this code to connect to the server:

```
mysqlpp::Connection conn(db, 0, user, pass, 3306);
```

this definitely has the right data in it.

and then, my sql server is the standard service from the MySQL install. And I'm pretty sure I used the standard settings. I can connect to it using the MySql Workbench and I edited some new tables and such but my own program doesn't seem to connect.

I read the documentation and I can't find anything specific that might suggest something why I can't connect.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, so many issues, so little time...

Have you checked that your program has permissions to access the database?

Does your program have the correct privileges?

Is your host name correct?

What errors are you getting?

What exception is thrown?

When you use the debugger, what line is the error on?

Here's my method:

```
sql::Connection * const
Manager ::
get_db_connection(void) const
{
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Use only one connection until proven that more connections will make
    //      the program more efficient or have a beneficial impact on the user.
    //  Thus the change in returning sql::Connection * rather than a smart pointer.
    //      A smart pointer will delete its contents.
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    static const char                   host_text[] = "tcp://127.0.0.1:3306/";
    static std::string                  host_name;
    if (!m_connection_initialized)
    {
        host_name = host_text;
        initialize_db_driver();
        host_name += m_dataset_info.m_dsn_name;
        try
        {
            m_p_connection = m_p_sql_driver->connect(host_name.c_str(),
                                                   m_dataset_info.m_user_name.c_str(),
                                                   m_dataset_info.m_password.c_str());
        }
        catch (sql::SQLException &e)
        {
            /*
            The MySQL Connector/C++ throws three different exceptions:

            - sql::MethodNotImplementedException (derived from sql::SQLException)
            - sql::InvalidArgumentException (derived from sql::SQLException)
            - sql::SQLException (derived from std::runtime_error)
            */
            wxString    wx_text = wxT("# ERR: SQLException in ");
            wx_text += wxT(__FILE__);
            wxLogDebug(wx_text);
            wx_text.Printf(wxT("# ERR: (%s) on line %d"),
                           __FUNCTION__,
                           __LINE__);
            wxLogDebug(wx_text);
            wx_text.Printf(wxT("# ERR: %s (MySQL error code: %d, SQLState: %s)"),
                e.what(),
                e.getErrorCode(),
                e.getSQLState());
            wxLogDebug(wx_text);
            wxLogDebug(wxT("Verify that mysqlcppconn.dll is in the PATH or in the working directory."));
            //      throw Manager_Connection_Not_Initialized();
            m_connection_initialized = false;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            std::cout << "Unhandled database SQL exception\n" << flush;
            m_connection_initialized = false;
        }           
        m_connection_initialized = true;
    }
    return m_p_connection;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm definitely going to try this out and let you know if this worked or not. I added a new user to my database but after changing the const char of the user to the new one my service can't start anymore and throws an error (well, windows throws an error) so I'm going to fix that first.

Comment: Apparently the service crashes when it tries to connect to the MySQL server. This didn't happen before and it only crashes with error 1067 when connecting with the new user. (root user doesn't crash but doesn't connect) Any suggestions?